# Removing a class from a tag

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

so i have a little bit of a problem with javascript.

I would like to check the checkbox and change the background color of the cell on click and remove the color and uncheck the checkbox if the user clicks on it again.

So far i have been able to change the color if a person clicks on the hyper link, the javascript below is an updated version of what i think it will be along the lines of.

this is the screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMdiW.jpg

this is how the markup is generated

```
<asp:TableCell Width="100%" ColumnSpan="2">                                
      <div id="checkboxes">
           <table width="100%" border="1">
                %foreach (var qv in rs)
                 {
                   var checkid = "chk" + qv.id;
                   var tdid = "td" + qv.id;                                                                                           
                 %
                 <tr>
                    <td width="100%">  
                       <a href="#/">                       
                       <input type="checkbox" value="@qv.id" name="<%=qv.id%>" />
                       <textbox><%=qv.text%></textbox>   
                       </a>                     
                    </td>                                            
                 </tr>
                <%}%>
        </table>
  </div>                                   
</asp:TableCell>
```

And this is the javascript and style ive tried so far

```
 $("a").click(function () {
            if($(this).parent().hasClass("selected")==true)
            {
                $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
                e.preventDefault();
            }                    
            else
            {
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
                e.preventDefault();
            }                
        });
```

style

```
td.selected {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to check  `== true` while using `.hasClass()`!

Comment: What's a `<textbox>`? O.o

Comment: Just toggle the class: `$(this).parent().toggleClass("selected");` No checks, no add/remove needed

Comment: Event handler can be written as `$('a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    e.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: Thanx to everyone who had helpful comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `e` as a parameter to your handler function. Also, you can just use `toggleClass` instead of doing all that checking.

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
  var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var isChecked = checkbox.prop('checked');
  if (isChecked) {
    checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    checkbox.prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```css
td.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">
      <a href="#/">
        Select Me
        <input type="checkbox">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Than you for this, its perfect, now to check the checkbox, would i have to just locate it and then check it in the click function aswell?

Comment: Updated the answer to check/uncheck the checkbox as well.

Comment: I've tried it as is on a new clean page and it works, so it has to be something I'm missing. I will hunt it down and find out but thanx!

Comment: Got it working 100% thanx, but sorry to bother you again, but is there a way to check a checkbox inside the a tag? Instead of the next or prev?

Comment: Yup, just use `.find()` instead of `.next()`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding a change event on `checkbox` itself:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href='#'>
        <input type='checkbox'>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll use this when i find the need!